# How can i set a Priority in PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Could I have help with following situation ? I have a website xyz.com and I'm using PHPMailer. When someone writes something in the "contact us" page, I receive an email, but is there a way for me to receive the email in "Important" or in the "Promotion" tab? Here you can see some details about actual code.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/functions.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';

session_start();

// Basic check to make sure the form was submitted.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
    redirectWithError("The form must be submitted with POST data.");
}

// Do some validation, check to make sure the name, email and message are valid.
if (empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    redirectWithError("Please complete the CAPTCHA.");
}

$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(CONTACTFORM_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
    $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
    $error = $errors[0];

    $recaptchaErrorMapping = [
        'missing-input-secret' => 'No reCAPTCHA secret key was submitted.',
        'invalid-input-secret' => 'The submitted reCAPTCHA secret key was invalid.',
        'missing-input-response' => 'No reCAPTCHA response was submitted.',
        'invalid-input-response' => 'The submitted reCAPTCHA response was invalid.',
        'bad-request' => 'An unknown error occurred while trying to validate your response.',
        'timeout-or-duplicate' => 'The request is no longer valid. Please try again.',
    ];

    $errorMessage = $recaptchaErrorMapping[$error];
    redirectWithError("Please retry the CAPTCHA: ".$errorMessage);
}

if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    redirectWithError("Please enter your name in the form.");
}

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    redirectWithError("Please enter your email address in the form.");
}

if (empty($_POST['subject'])) {
    redirectWithError("Please enter your message in the form.");
}

if (empty($_POST['message'])) {
    redirectWithError("Please enter your message in the form.");
}

if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    redirectWithError("Please enter a valid email address.");
}

if (strlen($_POST['message']) < 10) {
    redirectWithError("Please enter at least 10 characters in the message field.");
}

// Everything seems OK, time to send the email.

$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = CONTACTFORM_PHPMAILER_DEBUG_LEVEL;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_HOSTNAME;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_USERNAME;
    $mail->Password = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_PASSWORD;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
    $mail->Port = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_PORT;

    // Recipients
    $mail->setFrom(CONTACTFORM_FROM_ADDRESS, CONTACTFORM_FROM_NAME);
    $mail->addAddress(CONTACTFORM_TO_ADDRESS, CONTACTFORM_TO_NAME);
    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

    // Content
    $mail->Subject = "Dopenews - Contact us ".$_POST['Dopenews Studios'];
    $mail->Body    = <<<EOT
Name: {$_POST['name']}
Email: {$_POST['email']}
Message: 
{$_POST['message']}
EOT;

    $mail->send();
    redirectSuccess();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    redirectWithError("An error occurred while trying to send your message: ".$mail->ErrorInfo);
}
```

Comment: What "Important" or "Promotion" tab are you talking about?

Comment: Am talking about priorities like important or:urgent

Answer (score 2):

I *assume* you are referring to the Email Priority flag that can be set. I am not sure about *"is there a way for me to receive the mail in "Important" or in "Promotion" tab"* but to answer the title of your question:

It took me less than 60 seconds to read [**the PHPMailer documentation**](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html) and to find:

> PHPMailer Class:
>
> $Priority : integer|null
> Email priority.
>
> Options: null (default), 1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low. When null, the header is not set at all.

So usage in your code would be:

```
 $mail->Priority = 1; // High priority flag is set.
```

---

## A note about your use of Constants:

The [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) states:

> the scope of a constant is global. Constants can be accessed from anywhere in a script without regard to scope

You have a bunch of constants, such as **CONTACTFORM_SMTP_PASSWORD** and **CONTACTFORM_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY** , etc. etc., which - because they're constants - can be accessed from anywhere.

This might be great for you and easy to code, but this is a significant security hole on your system. External Password and Captcha keys and values should be overwritten and removed after use to minimise the risk of these being shown to someone they shouldn't be, with a very simple script (`print_r(get_defined_constants());`) run ***anywhere** in your PHP framework* all of your password and key values are immediately shown to whoever wants to find them....

---

## A Note about your Exception catching:

You are catching Exceptions incorrectly, you are using the `catch` block but the data within it is not the correct data. Also, you should not output to the user what went wrong as this can reveal sensitive server data that is best kept away from the general public.

Your code should be instead sent to your PHP error log rather than public display.

```
catch (Exception $ex) {
    redirectWithError("An error occurred while trying to send your message.");
    error_log("PHPMailer Exeption: ".print_r($ex->errorMessage(),true)); 
}
```

*It is noted that the PHPMailer documentation examples do simply `echo` the exceptions out directly, but this is for developer ease and not for public facing production code.*

**P.S** Your `try` block is also far too big, you only need to contain one or two lines in your PHPMailer try block, most the other lines do not throw exceptions so don't need to be wrapped in that block

Comment: Oh, actually am new in this am just begginner in php so I don't know much about it can you tell me that what should ? use now for SECURITIES too ? And for mail which would recieve in my important or promption tabs. As i can seei have to add  $mail->Priority = 1; // High priority flag is set.   But where should i put these lines  i mean on our mail reception or in smtp connection also should i also have to add anything in my confiq.php ? To define anything ?

Comment: @Reks2 you should add this line to your `try{ ... }` block along with all the other `$mail` settings.

Comment: ok brother can u do this for me ?  I shown my code there

Comment: Do u have fb, discord or Instagram?

Comment: Also how do know that am using contactform_smtp_password also what should i do then for increase my security???  Help me mate i am new in these i only knows simple basics can u help me with this to fix those also security ?. sir

Comment: not woring bro i`have added those priority in my php mail server but still i m not recieving mail on important or promotion tab its just same as it was before just in inbox

Comment: @Reks2 You may need to explore your Email client and find out what criteria they use to mark an email as "important" or "promotion". I can't tell you that.

Comment: @Reks2 you may need to ensure that your email passes all mailbox SPF, DKIM and other thresholds for not being spam. If you have an email that is not marked as "Safe" by the mailbox client then I doubt it would be allowed to be treated as "important".

Comment: i am Using gmail SMTP AND MAIL SERVER CAN U GIVE ME YOUR INSTAGRAM or facebook where i can contact you easily  ? or your email

Comment: can u help me in another matter too am using smf forums in my website but i used by webmaster mail as gmail but when anybody recieve email that mails wents to spam folder why ? this happens ? can u help me with this too ??